# How to use the replace function in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that takes a string from the user and replaces a word in the string with another using the replace function. I'm new to using the replace function but I have this so far.

```
def replacer(phrase, *args):
    # Sample:
    # replacer('hello world', ('l', 'r')) --> 'herro worrd'
    outputString = ""
    for char in phrase:
        foundFlag = False
        for arg in args:
            if char == arg:
                outputString += arg[1]
                foundFlag = True
                break
        if foundFlag:
            outputString += char
    return outputString
```

Comment: Are you looking for `phrase = phrase.replace('l', 'r')` ?

Comment: yes, but it has to replace at least 8 different letters, the letters that will be replaced is your choice and user has to pick which letter they want to replace. For example, the string is  HELLO and the user wants to replace E and O. As the programmer you can change E to anything and the O to anything, but for this example say that E changes to 3 and O changes to . The output should be H3LL0. Th

Comment: This is extremely unclear, can you rephrase/elaborate? I read the comments you made, but to no avail. Also, the indentation looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a custom function for replacing  chars in a string
python string object has a `builtin method` called `replace()`.

```
string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
```

It returns a copy of a string with all occurrence of sub string old replaced by new.

for eg:-

```
string = 'hello world'
new_string = string.replace('l','r', 2)
output==>  herro world
```

Comment: I know but I have to make a function that does the replacing without the replacer()

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have mixed up your logic. You are comparing each character with the tuple passed, and you only append to the `outputString` if the condition matches. Make the following changes:

Change

```
if char == arg:
```

to

```
if char == arg[0]:
```

and

```
if foundFlag:
```

to

```
if not foundFlag:
```

It will then print:

```
herro worrd
```

Comment: The string has to be entered by the user

Comment: I just showed you where to fix. The input method is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from dataclasses import replace


letter = '''Dear <|NAME|>
            you are selected
            Date:<|DATE|> 
'''

name = input("Enter your name\n")
date = input("Enter today's date\n")
letter = letter.replace('<|NAME|>',name)
letter = letter.replace('<|DATE|>',date)
print(letter)
```